# Calculating the number of "birthday days" in the birthday problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

Given 's' students in a room and 'd' days in the calendar year, what is the probability 'P' that there will be 'k' "birthday days"?

i.e., 'k = 1' means that everybody's birthday falls on the same day, 'k = 5' means that exactly 5 days of the year coincide with the birthday of at least one student, and 'k = s' means that everyone's birthday is unique.

Assume d ≥ s. 'k' will range from 1 to 's', and ∑P from k = 1 to k = s will be 1 (in other words, P(k) is a probability mass function).

**What I Know So Far:**

• The total number of ways for the students to have birthdays is d^s.

• P(1) = d/d^(s) (because there are 'd' days on which all students could all share the exact same birthday).

• P(s) = d!/(d^(s)(d-s)!) (because this is compliment of the solution to the standard birthday problem)

Any help/resources that get me closer to a formula for P(k) are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline: Under the usual assumptions, there are $d^s$ equally likely ways for the students to be assigned birthdays.

We now need to count the "favourables," the number of ways students can be assigned $k$ birthdays. The $k$ days on which Happy Birthday will be sung can be chosen in $\binom{d}{k}$ ways.

Now we multiply $\binom{d}{k}$ by the number of ways students can be assigned birthdays on some **specific** $k$ days, so that none of the $k$ days is missed. To calculate this, look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) on Stirling numbers of the Second Kind. We need to count the number of **onto** functions from an $s$-element set to a $k$-element set. There are also many questions/answers on MSE about the number of onto functions.

Comment: Thanks so much for tip on Stirling numbers of the second kind, that was exactly what I needed! The s^d vs. d^s mixup was just a typo on my part, but I appreciate the correction there too.

Comment: You  are welcome, I removed the remark after you edited.

Comment: Final comment: I also realized that, because the Stirling number of the second kind counts the number of ways to partition a set of 'n' labelled objects into 'k' nonempty **unlabelled** subsets, the Stirling number must be multiplied by 'k!' to account for all the "orderings" of the day subsets. The final formula works out to be P(k) = (nchoosek(d,k)S(s,k)k!)/(d^s). Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that;s right. Another way to think of it is that the usual Inclusion/Exclusion expression for the Stirling numbers involves dividing   a count by $k!$. For your application, you don't want to divide, so to undo the division built into the computation of Stirling numbers we must multiply $S(s,k)$ by $k!$.